# How to pass two values to ng-change function from ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is my  html code

```
<select ng-model="node.field.name" 
        data-nodrag 
        ng-options="value.label as value.label group by value.name for value in myOptions" 
        ng-change="getConditionsByType(node.field.name,value.name)">
</select>
```

When is use `getConditionsByType(node.field.name,value.name)` i am getting value.name as undefined

how can i access the values from ng-repeat when changing the options!

Comment: where are you passing the value.group?

Comment: could you please codepen or ,plunker

Comment: @Sajeetharan, it is value.name that was typo error

Comment: `ng-model` should be updated. you might be missing something else.

Comment: @maddog i am getting only value.label in the scope of ng-model but i want value.name along with that. did you get it?

Comment: @SyedRasheed use `value` instead of `value.label as value.label` then you will have whole `value`. You are using `label` so its giving you `label`

Comment: @maddog if i use value insead of value.label then dropdown will not bind the expected(value.label) instead it will bind the  whole object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`value` is not defined in the scope of `ng-change` - it is only defined in the microsyntax expression of `ng-options`.

Instead, make the model to be the "value" - i.e. the item of `myObjects`.

```
<select ng-model="selectedOption" 
        ng-options="value as value.label group by value.name for value in myOptions" 
        ng-change="onChange()">
</select>
```

This means that you can't set `node.field.name` to "value.name" directly - do so, in `ngChange` instead:

```
$scope.onChange = function(){
   $scope.node.field.name = selectedOption.name;
   getConditionsByType($scope.node.field.name, selectedOption.name)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this..

```
<select ng-model="node.field" 
        data-nodrag 
        ng-options="value as value.label group by value.name for value in myOptions" 
        ng-change="getConditionsByType(node.field.name, node.field.label)">
</select>
```

This is not setting only the `name` property of `node.field` but the entire `node.field`. Then you you can reference both `node.field.name` and `node.field.label`.

If I misunderstood and `value` and `node.field` don't have the same properties then use an intermediary field on scope to hold the value, watch that, and transform it to what you need to put in `node.field` (or do the transformation inside `ng-change`).

Comment: This *might* work, but we don't know from the question whether `node.field` object should exactly equal the selected item of `myOptions`. All we know is that `node.field.name` should be set to `myOption[X].name`

Comment: @NewDev ng-model name should be as node.filed.name only, this is a part of ui-tree, if is use node.field then i need to change the structure also

Comment: @SyedRasheed, unless I'm misunderstanding, it doesn't need to be that... Look at my answer - `ng-model` should be set to represent the selection - then, in `ng-change` assign the selection however you ned

Answer (score 2):

Check this one: http://plnkr.co/edit/RRWSYmEfCZu8aOrtNctl?p=preview

Main change

```
<select style="width: 100px;" ng-model="node.field.name" ng-change=temp() 
    ng-options="value.name as value.label group by value.name for value in myOptions"></select>
```